# Area of Cardioid $r=1+\sin(\theta)$ Using Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the area enclosed by $r=1+\sin \theta$ using Green's theorem.

What I have is

$\gamma(t)=(t,1+\sin t)$

$\gamma'(t)=(1,\cos t)$

Then $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(-1-\sin t+t\cos t)dt=-\pi$

Is it correct?

Comment: You got a negative number for an integral that was supposed to compute area.  Smells off a bit, don't you think?  Also, can you point out where you used Green's Theorem?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I used $\int_{\gamma}-ydx+xdy=\iint ds$

Comment: Isn't $\int_{\gamma}-ydx+xdy=2\iint ds?$  I think you just want $xdy$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form of Green's theorem that you used:
$$
    A(D) = \iint_D dx\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\oint_{\partial D} (x\,dy - y\,dx)
$$
applies when $x$ and $y$ are *cartesian* coordinates.  Your expression $\gamma(t) = (t,1+\sin t)$ expresses the curve in *polar* coordinates.  So you need to either state Green's theorem in polar coordinates, or express $\gamma$ in cartesian coordinates.

Let's do the latter.  The change of variables is $x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$.  So use
$$
    \gamma(t) = ((1+\sin t)\cos t,(1+\sin t)\sin t)
$$

As for the former, you can compute
\begin{align*}
    dx &= \cos\theta \,dr - r \sin\theta \,d\theta \\
    dy &= \sin\theta \,dr + r \cos\theta \,d\theta
\end{align*}
Then through a little [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), we get
$$
    dx \,dy = r\,dr\,d\theta
$$
and
$$
    x\,dy - y\,dx = r^2\,d\theta
$$
So Green's theorem tells us
$$
    A(D) = \int_D r\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\oint_{\partial D} r^2\,d\theta
$$
I think in many undergraduate multivariable calculus courses this identity isn't derived from Green's theorem, but it can be.  In any case, if $D$ is the region enclosed by the cardioid $r = 1 + \sin\theta$, then
$$
    A(D) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(1+\sin\theta)^2\,d\theta
$$

Comment: I was just in the middle of typing a comment about this.

Answer (score 3):

While I think Matthew Leingang work is more elegant and more general. Here is a slightly different approach.

Green's Theorem: 
$\iint (\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac {\partial P}{\partial y})\ dx\ dy = \oint P dx + Q dy$

Choose $P, Q$ such that $(\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac {\partial P}{\partial y}) = 1.$  We have a wide range of options here.  The point is to choose the easiest to work with.   e.g. Let $P,Q = 0,x$

$r = 1 + \sin \theta\\
x = r\cos \theta = (1+\sin\theta)\cos\theta\\
dx = -\sin\theta + \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta\ d\theta\\
y = r\sin \theta = (1+\sin\theta)\sin\theta\\
dy = \cos\theta + 2\sin\theta\cos\theta\ d\theta$

$\oint  x\ dy = \int_0^{2\pi} (\cos\theta + \frac 12 \sin 2\theta)(\cos\theta + \sin 2\theta)\ d\theta = \frac {3\pi}{2}$